# Data moved from hdfs to hive directory on performing load operation on hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-16.04

I loaded twitter data into my hive table after creating one, but after loading into hive table my hdfs directory shows no data present.

[image: select qury shows nothing][image: hive table location][image: flume stores data here][image][image]
i loaded data in table but it didnt move into it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load data to hive from HDFS without removing the source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567605/how-to-load-data-to-hive-from-hdfs-without-removing-the-source-file)

Comment: i have moved the data but the select query returns nothing. you can see my tweets table size is zero in last image

Comment: @Shu here it is